# O que significa "Auto packing the repository for optimum performance"?

Tags: git, versionamento

Fui dar `git push` num repositório remoto e a seguinte mensagem apareceu:

```
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
```

Imediatamente interrompi pois achei que escrevi um comando errado. No SOEn diz que isso ocorre pelo grande número de **objetos soltos não embalados**. 
O que é exatamente isso? Existe algum problema em interromper esse processo ou é necessário fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O *auto packing* serve para que o GIT recrie os índices internos dos arquivos (nenhum *commit* ou arquivo é modificado). É um procedimento interno que irá agilizar exibição de logs, tarefas de *push/pull*, etc.

Já o `git gc` é o *garbage collector* do GIT, ou seja, ele coleta todo o lixo no repositório. Copiado do manual:

> git gc tries very hard to be safe about the garbage it collects.

O `git gc` é muito cauteloso no que ele remove do repositório, colaborando também para melhorar o desempenho. Então você pode executar o procedimento sem medo.

[Esse artigo](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Internamente-Manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-Recupera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-Dados) no manual do GIT em português explica detalhadamente como o *garbage collector* funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece para agilizar o processo quando o Git identifica que a movimentação envolve muitos arquivos.

Para facilitar, você pode pensar no `packing` como o Git fazendo uma compressão *.zip* dos arquivos para mover eles, ficando menores e mais leves, e por sua vez pensar no `git gc` como a ação para descomprimir os arquivos.

(isso foi um exemplo para entendimento, não significa que ele gera um arquivo *.zip*)

Se quiser informações mais detalhadas: [Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery)